JavaFX click sound effect delay
So I'm doing this javaFX project and I wanted to add click sound effect to the buttons, but there is always a big delay (up to 1 second), I have tried to use AudioClip and MediaPlayer and there is no difference, the sound clip is in mp3. I'm using scene builder so there is no (JavaFX) code for the buttons, the functionality of them is chosen throught scene builder.
This is the code of the Controller class.
package game.gui;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent; import javafx.fxml.FXML; import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader; import javafx.scene.Node; import javafx.scene.Parent; import javafx.scene.Scene; import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip; import javafx.scene.media.Media; import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer; import javafx.scene.media.MediaView; import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File; import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {
private AudioClip clickSoundClip;
public void clickSoundEffect() {
    clickSoundClip = new AudioClip(getClass().getResource("sounds/click-effect.mp3").toString());
    clickSoundClip.play();
}

@FXML
public void switchToRulesScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    switchScene("rules.fxml", event);
}

@FXML
public void switchToHomeScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    switchScene("gui.fxml", event);
}

@FXML
public void exitGame() {
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
public void switchToChoiceScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    switchScene("ChoiceScene.fxml", event);
}

private void switchScene(String fxmlFile, ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}


The problem was in the sound file, I just needed to trim it...

Also, why not just load the sound clip once, maybe use lazy loading, and just store it in a variable?  Reloading each time seems a waste unless you're extremely memory constrained.
